# Visualforce Page not loading on iPad

Tags: visualforce, ios

I'm trying to load a visualforce page on an iPad, but when I click on the button the page is blank and nothing is showing. The VF page is loading fine when I'm using SF on a computer. I tried to turn off "Lock sessions to the domain in which they were first used" as mentioned in another blog and still no success.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001bHeXQAU&title=visualforce-page-is-not-loaded-after-session-timeout-on-salesforce-for-ios-with-lock-session-to-the-domain&_ga=2.212609555.606933463.1669818457-17669123.1649776257

Thanks in advance for your help,
Raph

Comment: This will be tough to troubleshoot. Have you tried stripping down the VF page to be barebones to see what aspects of it that the iPad has an issue with? Assumedly, if _other_ VF pages load on the iPad, then this issue is exclusive to the page and its controller.

Comment: Hi nbrown, I have multiple VF pages and none are loading on the iPad but they are working on a computer. I tried on an iPhone and I received this error message: "Page doesn't exist, Enter a valid URL and try again" It's like the mobile app doesn't like the redirect to a VF.

Comment: `Setup -> Develop -> Pages. Once there, you need to make sure that the Available for Salesforce mobile apps setting is checked.` - does this help?

Comment: Hi All, it's working now! The only modification I did was to Set "Lock sessions to the domain in which they were first used" to OFF in Session Settings as mentioned in my original and wait a few hours. I don't know if it's related but it's working now. Thanks guys!